# IWebDriver opens two new windows instead of one in c#

Tags: webdriver

When I click on a link in an application manually it only opens one new window but with IWebDriver it opens two new windows.

IWebElemnet  element = WebDriverActions.Driver.FindElement(By.Id(controlId));

element.Click();

Comment: provide more infomation

Comment: Please recheck your locator might be it is identify different locator. Also it is good if you share sample code with html source code for that particular element.